# How to access table data from outside the controller in javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm trying to create a material inventory program that uses a tableview.  I have a controller that will show statistics based on that tableview but I'm not sure how to access the live data from that view.

My MainApp loads the last saved table and my MaterialOverviewController has the tableview.

I have a RootLayoutController which is my main layout controller which has a simple file menu but also is where the OnFloorStatsController is loaded from.

I can obviously create a new MainApp when the OnFloorStatsController is loaded but this only loads the sample data that was entered by default.

How do I access the live data from the MainApp?

Here is my MainApp code:

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;

    private ObservableList<Material> materialData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("Label Inventory");
        this.primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/1462487405_Mask.png"));

        initRootLayout();
        showMaterialOverview();
    }

    public MainApp() {
        // Add some sample data

    }

    public ObservableList<Material> getMaterialData() {
        return materialData;
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout and tries to load the last opened
     * material file.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class
                    .getResource("RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            RootLayoutController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Try to load last opened person file.
        File file = getMaterialFilePath();
        if (file != null) {
            loadMaterialDataFromFile(file);
        }
    }




    public void showMaterialOverview() {
        try {
            // Load material overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("MaterialOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane materialOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set material overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(materialOverview);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            MaterialOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void showOnFloorStatistics() {
        try {
            // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("OnFloorStats.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Material On Floor");
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            // Set the material into the controller.
            OnFloorStatsController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.start(dialogStage);

            dialogStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void showBarChartTest() {
        try {
            // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("BarChartTestLayout.fxml"));
            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("Detailed Bar Chart");

//
            dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
            dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);

            // Set the material into the controller.
            BarChartTest controller = loader.getController();
            controller.start(dialogStage);

            dialogStage.show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And here is my MaterialOverViewController code:

```
public class MaterialOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<Material> materialTable;


    private List<Material> materialId;

    public TableView<Material> getMaterialTable() {
        return materialTable;
    }

//    public void setMaterialTable(TableView<Material> materialTable) {
//        this.materialTable = materialTable;
    }

    private ObservableList<Integer> rollsTotal = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private ObservableList<String> materialNames = FXCollections.observableArrayList();



    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public MaterialOverviewController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        materialTotal = 0;
        // Initialize the material table with columns.
        pONumberColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().pONumberProperty());
        materialNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().materialNameProperty());
        materialIdColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().materialIdProperty());
        materialWidthColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().materialWidthProperty().asObject());
        qtyOrderedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().qtyOrderedProperty().asObject());
        qtyReceivedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().qtyReceivedProperty().asObject());
        qtyBackOrderedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().qtyBackOrderedProperty().asObject());
//        qtyBackOrderedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().qtyBackOrderedProperty().asObject());
        qtyOnFloorColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().qtyOnFloorProperty().asObject());
//        dateOrderedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateOrderedProperty().asString());
        dateOrderedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateOrderedProperty().asString());
        estArrivalColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().dateExpectedProperty().asString());
        supplierColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().supplierProperty());

        // Clear material details.
        showMaterialDetails(null);

        // Listen for selection changes and show the material details when changed.
        materialTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showMaterialDetails(newValue));

    }

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;

        // Add observable list data to the table
        materialTable.setItems(mainApp.getMaterialData());
    }

    private void showMaterialDetails(Material material) {
        if (material != null) {
            // Fill the labels with info from the material object.
            pONumberLabel.setText(material.getPoNumber());
            materialIdLabel.setText(material.getMaterialId());
            materialNameLabel.setText(material.getMaterialName());
            materialWidthLabel.setText(String.valueOf(material.getMaterialWidth()));
            qtyOrderedLabel.setText(Integer.toString(material.getQtyOrdered()));
            qtyRecievedLabel.setText(Integer.toString(material.getQtyReceived()));
            qtyBackOrderedLabel.setText(Integer.toString(material.getQtyOrdered()-material.getQtyReceived()));
//            qtyBackOrderedLabel.setText(Integer.toString(material.getQtyBackOrdered()));
            qtyOnFloorLabel.setText(Integer.toString(material.getQtyOnFloor()));
//            dateOrderedLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(material.getDateOrdered()));
//            dateOrderedLabel.equals(DateUtil.format(material.getDateOrdered()));
//            dateOrderedLabel.setText(DatePicker(String.valueOf(material.getDateOrdered());
//            estArrivalLabel.setText(material.getSupplier());
            supplierLabel.setText(material.getSupplier());

            String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
//            dateTestTextField.setText(DateUtil.format(material.getBirthday()));
            dateOrderedLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(material.getDateOrdered()));
            estArrivalLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(material.getDateExpected()));
            //TODO: set running material totals
//            getMaterialNames(Arrays.asList(material));
            handleSelectMaterial();

        } 
        }
    }


    public List getMaterialNames(List<Material> materials) {

        for (Material name : materials) {
            mainApp.getMaterialData();
            if (!materialNames.contains(name)) {
                materialNames.add(name.getMaterialName());
            }
        }
        for (String name : materialNames) {
            materialTextField.setText(name + "\n");
        }
        return Arrays.asList(materialNames);
    }


    }

}
```

Here is the bit of code that works from my RootLayoutController but I'm not sure why I can't do the same thing from the OnFloorStatsController:

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
}

@FXML
private void handlePrint() {

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MaterialOverview.fxml"));
    try {
        AnchorPane frame = fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MaterialOverviewController c = fxmlLoader.getController();

    //Loads data into table
    c.setMainApp(mainApp);
```

I just need access to the live data from the MaterialOvewViewController

Here's the OnFloorStatsController:

```
    private MainApp mainApp;
    public TableView<Material> material;
    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     *
     * @param mainApp
     */

    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
    }



//    final static String austria = "14532";
//    final static String brazil = "78333";
//    final static String france = "40443";
//    final static String italy = "72825";
//    final static String usa = "72829";


    public void start(Stage stage) {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
        fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MaterialOverview.fxml"));
        try {
            AnchorPane frame = fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        MaterialOverviewController c = fxmlLoader.getController();

        //Loads data into table
        c.setMainApp(mainApp);

        stage.setTitle("Material On Floor");
        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final BarChart<String, Number> bc =
                new BarChart<String, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
        bc.setTitle("Material On Floor");
        xAxis.setLabel("Material");
        yAxis.setLabel("Quantity");


        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("6 inch");
        Integer floorTotal = 0;


        for (Material id :mainApp.getMaterialData()) {
            if (id.getMaterialWidth() < 6.9) {
                floorTotal = id.getQtyOnFloor();
                for (Material size : mainApp.getMaterialData()) {
                    if ( id.getMaterialId().equalsIgnoreCase(size.getMaterialId()) &&
                            size.getMaterialWidth() == id.getMaterialWidth()) {
                        floorTotal += size.getQtyOnFloor();
                    }
                    else {
                        floorTotal = id.getQtyOnFloor();
                    }
```

Comment: Sorry about that....I've reduced the code.  I managed to get the RootLayoutController  to access the live tableview for printing but I can't seem to duplicate it from the OnFloorStatsController

Comment: Thank you! As I understand you, you load a RootLayout, and after that you load a MaterialOverView into your RootLayout, and then you want to be able to show a View with statistic data calculated from the data in the table? So, why you are not able to do this? You have a handle to data in you main and in your MaterialOverView.

Comment: Not sure...I keep getting a null pointer exception in my OnFloorStatsController at the "c.setMainApp(mainApp)" line

Comment: Can you please add the OnFloorStatsController source code?

Comment: Just added the OnFloorStatsController code, thanks!